# Terraform - Cognito Invite message with more than 20k characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I've been having a little issue. I'm using a Cognito pool on AWS, and I'd like to send more than 20 thousand characters for the invitation email.

I've been successful in doing so by connecting it to SES.
If I use the console, I can add more than 20k characters in the **Email message** of my invitation.

The error comes when I want to declare the Email Message with Terraform.

I get the error ->

```
admin_create_user_config.0.invite_message_template.0.email_message" cannot be longer than 20000 characters
```

However, my Cognito pool has been declared to use the `DEVELOPER` option in Terraform, and it works fine when I input the message manually via the console.

Here is my configuration ->

This is called from my main file.

```
  email_message_invitation = file("${path.module}/files/cognito/invitation_message.html")
  email_sending_account_cognito = "DEVELOPER"
  ses_source_arn_cognito = var.ses_source_arn_cognito_custom

  ## Requires a valid email address
  reply_to_email_cognito = var.reply_to_email_cognito_custom
  from_email_address_cognito = var.from_email_address_cognito_custom
```

And here is the code inside the module I created for Cognito ->

```
   admin_create_user_config {
        allow_admin_create_user_only = var.allow_admin_create_user_only

        invite_message_template {
            email_message = var.email_message_invitation
            email_subject = var.email_subject_invitation
            sms_message   = var.sms_message_invitation
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
    email_configuration {
        email_sending_account = var.email_sending_account_cognito
        source_arn = var.ses_source_arn_cognito
        reply_to_email_address = var.reply_to_email_cognito
        from_email_address = var.from_email_address_cognito
    }
```

It seems like the call to the API restricts the body of the mail to 20k via terraform; however, the API calls on AWS doesn't.

I hope someone can help me :D

Comment: I would recommend opening a github issue for the terraform aws provider regarding this.

Comment: Is that error happening at the plan or apply stage?

Comment: at the plan. I'm going to close this issue. Apparently cognito doesn't support more than 20k characters in emails even if you use SES. I might be wrong, but this is what I found. I compressed my HTML and removed unnecessary comments to go under 20k characters